# Shoulda superclass mismatch on unit tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, shoulda

Trying to write a simple unit test using shoulda and rails 3.

**test/unit/user_test.rb**

```
class UserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  should validate_presence_of(:password, :on => :create)
  should validate_presence_of(:handle, :email)
  should validate_confirmation_of(:password)
  should validate_length_of(:handle, :within => 6..15)
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:handle)
  should validate_format_of(:handle, :with => /\A\w+\z/i)
  should validate_length_of(:email, :within => 6..100)
end
```

Relevant parts of **Gemfile**

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.12'
end
```

When I try to run this using `rake test --trace` I receive the following error:

```
** Execute test:units
/Users/removed/removed/removed/app_name/test/unit/user_test.rb:5: superclass mismatch for class UserTest (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
```

I understand the error, I just don't get where another UserTest class would be defined that's giving me this issue.  Any thoughts?

Mike

Comment: What does `find . | xargs grep -l UserTest` return? Run it from your project's root.

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot - turns out I had copied the code from this unit test into another unit test hence defining UserTest twice.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I guess that's a relatively frequent mistake ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the output of `find . | xargs grep -l UserTest` against accidental duplicated uses of the class name.

Comment: You may want to add a `-name '*.rb'` to your `find`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could imagine avoiding this mistake is by doing the following:

```
UserTest = Class.new(Test::Unit::TestCase)
class UserTest # Or class UserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase is also allowed
  should validate_presence_of(:password, :on => :create)
  should validate_presence_of(:handle, :email)
  should validate_confirmation_of(:password)
  should validate_length_of(:handle, :within => 6..15)
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:handle)
  should validate_format_of(:handle, :with => /\A\w+\z/i)
  should validate_length_of(:email, :within => 6..100)
end
```

if you were to repeat

```
UserTest = Class.new(Test::Unit::TestCase) # repeated
```

you'd get

```
warning: already initialized constant UserTest
```

But this approach would look a little weird.

Comment: Yeah - it would work but it's overkill to a more subtle problem: stupid programming.  I'm working on a fix for that, but haven't gotten it right yet. :)

Comment: @Mike: Send me the patch when you create it! :)